# Неправильное отображение csv файла в excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

После импорта данных в excel неправильно отображается файл.
Вот из excel. Тут два продукта. Они Должны быть на отдельной строчке, а не через колонку.:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот часть кода:

```
for item in result_three:
    done = []
    for i in item:
        element = i.split('\n')
        try:
            element = f'{element[0]} {element[1]}, {element[2]};'
            done.append(element)
        except:
            element = f'{element[0]} {element[1]}, {element[1]};'
            done.append(element)
    result_four.append(done)
```

Вот как выглядят данные на выходе:

```
['Тип кузова - Компактный кроссовер, Компактный кроссовер;Количество дверей - 5, 5;Количество мест - 5, 5;Дорожный просвет - 170 мм, 170 мм;Объем багажника - 455-1200 л, 455-1200 л;', 'Длина - 4200 мм, 4200 мм;Ширина - 1790 мм, 1790 мм;Высота - 1600 мм, 1600 мм;Колесная база - 2570 мм, 2570 мм;Колея передних колес - 1540 мм, 1540 мм;Колея задних колес - 1530 мм, 1530 мм;Радиус разворота - 5 м, 5 м;', 'Расстояние от подушки переднего сиденья до потолка - 960 мм, 960 мм;Расстояние от подушки заднего сиденья до потолка - 974 мм, 974 мм;Ширина салона для первого ряда - 1400 мм, 1400 мм;Ширина салона для второго ряда сидений - 1385 мм, 1385 мм;Ширина салона спереди на уровне плеч - 1382 мм, 1382 мм;Ширина салона сзади на уровне плеч - 1340 мм, 1340 мм;Пространство для ног передних пассажиров - 1020 мм, 1020 мм;Пространство для ног задних пассажиров - 918 мм, 918 мм;', 'Тип - Бензиновый, Бензиновый;Экологический класс - ЕВРО 5, ЕВРО 5;Объем - 1498 см3, 1498 см3;Максимальная мощность - 107 л.с. (79 кВт) при 6000 об/мин, 107 л.с. (79 кВт) при 6000 об/мин;Максимальный крутящий момент - 142 Н•м при 4000 об/мин, 142 Н•м при 4000 об/мин;Расположение двигателя - Переднее поперечное, Переднее поперечное;Конструкция - С водяным охлаждением, рядный, С водяным охлаждением, рядный;Число цилиндров - 4, 4;Число клапанов - 16, 16;Газораспределительный механизм - VVT, VVT;Степень сжатия - 10, 10;', 'Тип - Механическая КПП, ручное управление, Автоматическая КПП, гидромеханическая;Количество передач - 5, 5;', 'Разгон 0-100 км/ч - 11.4 с, 11.4 с;Максимальная скорость - 170 км/ч, 160 км/ч;', 'Загородный цикл - 6.3 л, 6.5 л;Смешанный цикл - 7.5 л, 7.5 л;Объем топливного бака - 52 л, 52 л;', 'Тип привода - Передний, Передний;Рулевой механизм - Шестерня-рейка, Шестерня-рейка;Рулевое управление - Электроусилитель, Электроусилитель;Тормоза передние - Дисковые, Дисковые;Тормоза задние - Дисковые, Дисковые;Подвеска передняя - Независимая, пружинная, типа МакФерсон, со стабилизатором поперечной устойчивости, Независимая, пружинная, типа МакФерсон, со стабилизатором поперечной устойчивости;Подвеска задняя - Полузависимая, рычажная, пружинная, с гидравлическими, телескопическими амортизаторами, Полузависимая, рычажная, пружинная, с гидравлическими, телескопическими амортизаторами;', 'Снаряженная масса - 1400 кг, 1425 кг;Максимальная полная масса - 1715 кг, 1740 кг;', 'Размерность шин - 215/60 R17, 215/60 R17;Диски - Легкосплавные, алюминиевые, Легкосплавные, алюминиевые;Запасное колесо - Докатка (Т155/90 R16), Докатка (Т155/90 R16);']
```

Или так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот как записывается в csv:

```
    def write_to_csv(self, data):
        """ Добавляем данные """
        with open('data.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow((
                data[0],
                data[1],
                data[2],
                data[3],
                data[4],
                data[5],
                data[6],
                data[7],
                data[8],
                data[9],
            ))
```

Пробовал изменять код на так:

```
for item in result_three:
    done = []
    for i in item:
        element = i.split('\n')
        try:
            element = f'{element[0]} {element[1]}, {element[2]};\n' # Здесь \n
            done.append(element)
        except:
            element = f'{element[0]} {element[1]}, {element[1]};\n' # И здесь \n
            done.append(element)
    result_four.append(done)
```

но в итоге получается такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также пробовал указывать разделитель на точку с запятой, но все получается в одну строчку и разделитель через колонку.

Изменил код здесь:

```
for item in result_three:
    done = []
    for i in item:
        element = i.split('\n')
        try:
            element = f'{element[0]} {element[1]}, {element[2]}\t' # Поставил \t
            done.append(element)
        except:
            element = f'{element[0]} {element[1]}, {element[1]}\t' # Поставил \t
            done.append(element)
    result_four.append(done)
return result_four
```

И теперь отображается все в одну строчку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все-таки как должны выводиться данные, обычно в csv данные выводятся следующим образом: Самая верхняя строка заголовок, в которой находятся названия столбцов, например (Тип кузова, Количество дверей и тд), а ниже данные в соответствии с названием столбцов. Во входном списке у вас данные, но почему-то на каждый столбец по 2 значения ('Тип кузова - Компактный кроссовер, Компактный кроссовер;), здесь они одинаковые, можно одно отбросить, но как быть с Загородный цикл - **6.3 л**, **6.5 л**. Если разъяснить эти вопросы, то можно будет в одну таблицу добавлять не одну машину, а сколько угодно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно или добавлять разделитель вручную, и писать напрямую в файл вручную без модуля csv, или использовать модуль csv без ручного добавления разделителя. Совмещать оба подхода я не рекомендую, вы так только запутаетесь.

Если вы уже добавили разделитель:

```
data = [
    "Тип кузова - Компактный кроссовер, Компактный кроссовер;Количество дверей - 5, 5;Количество мест - 5, 5;Дорожный просвет - 170 мм, 170 мм;Объем багажника - 455-1200 л, 455-1200 л;",
    "Длина - 4200 мм, 4200 мм;Ширина - 1790 мм, 1790 мм;Высота - 1600 мм, 1600 мм;Колесная база - 2570 мм, 2570 мм;Колея передних колес - 1540 мм, 1540 мм;Колея задних колес - 1530 мм, 1530 мм;Радиус разворота - 5 м, 5 м;",
    "Расстояние от подушки переднего сиденья до потолка - 960 мм, 960 мм;Расстояние от подушки заднего сиденья до потолка - 974 мм, 974 мм;Ширина салона для первого ряда - 1400 мм, 1400 мм;Ширина салона для второго ряда сидений - 1385 мм, 1385 мм;Ширина салона спереди на уровне плеч - 1382 мм, 1382 мм;Ширина салона сзади на уровне плеч - 1340 мм, 1340 мм;Пространство для ног передних пассажиров - 1020 мм, 1020 мм;Пространство для ног задних пассажиров - 918 мм, 918 мм;",
    "Тип - Бензиновый, Бензиновый;Экологический класс - ЕВРО 5, ЕВРО 5;Объем - 1498 см3, 1498 см3;Максимальная мощность - 107 л.с. (79 кВт) при 6000 об/мин, 107 л.с. (79 кВт) при 6000 об/мин;Максимальный крутящий момент - 142 Н•м при 4000 об/мин, 142 Н•м при 4000 об/мин;Расположение двигателя - Переднее поперечное, Переднее поперечное;Конструкция - С водяным охлаждением, рядный, С водяным охлаждением, рядный;Число цилиндров - 4, 4;Число клапанов - 16, 16;Газораспределительный механизм - VVT, VVT;Степень сжатия - 10, 10;",
    "Тип - Механическая КПП, ручное управление, Автоматическая КПП, гидромеханическая;Количество передач - 5, 5;",
    "Разгон 0-100 км/ч - 11.4 с, 11.4 с;Максимальная скорость - 170 км/ч, 160 км/ч;",
    "Загородный цикл - 6.3 л, 6.5 л;Смешанный цикл - 7.5 л, 7.5 л;Объем топливного бака - 52 л, 52 л;",
    "Тип привода - Передний, Передний;Рулевой механизм - Шестерня-рейка, Шестерня-рейка;Рулевое управление - Электроусилитель, Электроусилитель;Тормоза передние - Дисковые, Дисковые;Тормоза задние - Дисковые, Дисковые;Подвеска передняя - Независимая, пружинная, типа МакФерсон, со стабилизатором поперечной устойчивости, Независимая, пружинная, типа МакФерсон, со стабилизатором поперечной устойчивости;Подвеска задняя - Полузависимая, рычажная, пружинная, с гидравлическими, телескопическими амортизаторами, Полузависимая, рычажная, пружинная, с гидравлическими, телескопическими амортизаторами;",
    "Снаряженная масса - 1400 кг, 1425 кг;Максимальная полная масса - 1715 кг, 1740 кг;",
    "Размерность шин - 215/60 R17, 215/60 R17;Диски - Легкосплавные, алюминиевые, Легкосплавные, алюминиевые;Запасное колесо - Докатка (Т155/90 R16), Докатка (Т155/90 R16);",
]

with open("file.csv", "w") as file:
    for line in data:
        file.write(line)
        file.write('\n')  # В строках переноса строки нет, поэтому нужно добавить его вручную
        # Или вместо двух file.write сделать print(line, file=file) - перенос строки будет добавлен автоматически
```

[image: Скриншот]

Каждый элемент исходного списка для excel будет отдельной строкой таблицы, каждый кусок строки между разделителями (точкой с запятой) - отдельной ячейкой.

---

Пример использования модуля csv (тут не нужно добавлять вручную никакие разделители, переносы строк, и т.д.):

```
data = [
    [
        "Тип кузова - Компактный кроссовер, Компактный кроссовер",
        "Количество дверей - 5, 5",
        "Количество мест - 5, 5",
        "Дорожный просвет - 170 мм, 170 мм",
        "Объем багажника - 455-1200 л, 455-1200 л",
    ],
    [
        "Длина - 4200 мм, 4200 мм",
        "Ширина - 1790 мм, 1790 мм",
        "Высота - 1600 мм, 1600 мм",
        "Колесная база - 2570 мм, 2570 мм",
        "Колея передних колес - 1540 мм, 1540 мм",
        "Колея задних колес - 1530 мм, 1530 мм",
        "Радиус разворота - 5 м, 5 м",
    ],
]


import csv


with open("file.csv", "w", newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')  # разделитель указывается в параметрах writer-а
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Результат:

[image: Скриншот]

Каждый подсписок в списке `data` для excel будет отдельной строкой таблицы, каждый элемент подсписка - отдельной ячейкой.

Если нужно, чтобы у вас два продукта были на двух строках, то нужно создать список из двух подсписков, в каждом из подсписков все данные по продуктам.

Answer (score 2):

Написал комментарий, пока ответа нет напишу свое виденье решения проблемы.

1. Данные странные не много, поэтому хочется их почистить:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

data = ['Тип кузова - Компактный кроссовер, Компактный кроссовер;Количество дверей - 5, 5;Количество мест - 5, 5;Дорожный просвет - 170 мм, 170 мм;Объем багажника - 455-1200 л, 455-1200 л;', 'Длина - 4200 мм, 4200 мм;Ширина - 1790 мм, 1790 мм;Высота - 1600 мм, 1600 мм;Колесная база - 2570 мм, 2570 мм;Колея передних колес - 1540 мм, 1540 мм;Колея задних колес - 1530 мм, 1530 мм;Радиус разворота - 5 м, 5 м;', 'Расстояние от подушки переднего сиденья до потолка - 960 мм, 960 мм;Расстояние от подушки заднего сиденья до потолка - 974 мм, 974 мм;Ширина салона для первого ряда - 1400 мм, 1400 мм;Ширина салона для второго ряда сидений - 1385 мм, 1385 мм;Ширина салона спереди на уровне плеч - 1382 мм, 1382 мм;Ширина салона сзади на уровне плеч - 1340 мм, 1340 мм;Пространство для ног передних пассажиров - 1020 мм, 1020 мм;Пространство для ног задних пассажиров - 918 мм, 918 мм;', 'Тип - Бензиновый, Бензиновый;Экологический класс - ЕВРО 5, ЕВРО 5;Объем - 1498 см3, 1498 см3;Максимальная мощность - 107 л.с. (79 кВт) при 6000 об/мин, 107 л.с. (79 кВт) при 6000 об/мин;Максимальный крутящий момент - 142 Н•м при 4000 об/мин, 142 Н•м при 4000 об/мин;Расположение двигателя - Переднее поперечное, Переднее поперечное;Конструкция - С водяным охлаждением, рядный, С водяным охлаждением, рядный;Число цилиндров - 4, 4;Число клапанов - 16, 16;Газораспределительный механизм - VVT, VVT;Степень сжатия - 10, 10;', 'Тип - Механическая КПП, ручное управление, Автоматическая КПП, гидромеханическая;Количество передач - 5, 5;', 'Разгон 0-100 км/ч - 11.4 с, 11.4 с;Максимальная скорость - 170 км/ч, 160 км/ч;', 'Загородный цикл - 6.3 л, 6.5 л;Смешанный цикл - 7.5 л, 7.5 л;Объем топливного бака - 52 л, 52 л;', 'Тип привода - Передний, Передний;Рулевой механизм - Шестерня-рейка, Шестерня-рейка;Рулевое управление - Электроусилитель, Электроусилитель;Тормоза передние - Дисковые, Дисковые;Тормоза задние - Дисковые, Дисковые;Подвеска передняя - Независимая, пружинная, типа МакФерсон, со стабилизатором поперечной устойчивости, Независимая, пружинная, типа МакФерсон, со стабилизатором поперечной устойчивости;Подвеска задняя - Полузависимая, рычажная, пружинная, с гидравлическими, телескопическими амортизаторами, Полузависимая, рычажная, пружинная, с гидравлическими, телескопическими амортизаторами;', 'Снаряженная масса - 1400 кг, 1425 кг;Максимальная полная масса - 1715 кг, 1740 кг;', 'Размерность шин - 215/60 R17, 215/60 R17;Диски - Легкосплавные, алюминиевые, Легкосплавные, алюминиевые;Запасное колесо - Докатка (Т155/90 R16), Докатка (Т155/90 R16);']
data = ''join(data)
# Внес правку для того что бы ключи сохранялись всегда в одном порядке, спасибо за замечание @insolor
data = OrderedDict( [
    (x.split('-')[0].strip(), x.split('-')[1].strip().split(',')[0]) # Делим каждую строку на 2 подстроки (1- ключ, 2-значение)
    for x in data.split(';') # Разделили строку на список строк по ";"
    if x ] ) # есть пустые строки - их пропускаем
```

Теперь данные выглядят так:

```
data = {'Тип кузова': 'Компактный кроссовер', 'Количество дверей': '5', 'Количество мест': '5', ...}
```

Для удобства работы со словарями в библиотеке для работы с csv есть класс DictWriter.
Для начала определим какие у нас поля (названия столбцов):

```
fieldnames = list(data.keys())
```

Далее приступим к записи:

```
with open("result.csv", 'w+', encoding="1251", newline='') as fl:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(fl, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=';')
    writer.writeheader() # Запись название столбцов
    writer.writerow(data) # Запись данных
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: fieldnames лучше конкретно прописать, а не просто брать ключи из словаря, т.к. в зависимости от версии Python словарь может помнить или не помнить порядок, в котором ключи добавлялись. Лучше жестко прописать порядок столбцов, чтобы не было неожиданностей.

Comment: @insolor,  Согласен, обычно так и делаю, но хотелось создать рабочий пример, при этом не переписывая 49 полей вручную)

Comment: @insolor, добавил OrderedDict, спасибо за замечание

Comment: @АндрейКоробейников, спасибо за отклик, полезный код, можно взять на заметку. Правда, до вашего ответа я не дошел, помог insolor